# The safest way for saving unexpected time formats in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date-format

I have to collect dates from different formats and save them in MySQL Filed `Date` (YYYY-MM-DD I reckon), so how can i change formats like 12/24/2010, 24/12/2010, 12-10-2010 and stuff like this with PHP ?

I know there is `mktime`, `strtotime` but how can i do it safely ?

UPDATE: safe from accuracy point of view! :)

Comment: can you define `safely`?  Do you mean with 100% accuracy?  Or safe from abuse?  Or from a security standpoint?

Comment: If you have control over the entry GUI, it may be useful to sidestep the problem: provide a nice selectable calendar (there are helpers for this in most languages and frameworks - e.g. this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ ). That way, the user can select and visually verify the correct date, and you'll convert it into the desired format.

Comment: @Piskvor: Thanks for answer as I am collecting these dates from emails i can't take control over it.

Comment: Never mind then. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't: consider mm/dd/yy v yy/mm/dd v dd/mm/yy for the date November 9th 2010.

You would need to know that format that they did it in before hand. There is no one-off solution.

Comment: @shamittor: in case of 10/10/10 there is no problem is it will be 2010/10/10 (YYYYMMDD) and same 2010/10/10 in (YYYYYDDMM)

Comment: which is why I totally changed it to 11/9/10 in the answer. :P

Answer (score 2):

> ...formats like 12/24/2010, 24/12/2010...

Your basic problem here is that `dd/mm/yyyy` is often indistinguishable from `mm/dd/yyyy`.

If you get `11/12/2010`, how will you know which format it is supposed to be? `strtotime()` won't help you there.

If you do plan to use `strtotime()`, it's worth pointing out that if you give it `11/12/2010` (ie with slash separators), it will treat it as `mm/dd/yyyy`, but if you give it `11-12-2010` (dash separators), it will treat it as `dd-mm-yyyy`. But because both formats are commonly written both ways, that distinction is not only pointless but actually makes the `strtotime()` function too unpredictable for real-life use.

If you do already know the format of any specific incoming date string, then your best best is to split it into its component parts using `preg_match()` or similar, and re-build it using `mktime()`.

If you don't know the format that was intended by the user then you can guess, but if its ambiguous then there's always a chance you'll get it wrong.

If this is coming from a web site input form, you would be better advised to provide a front-end control in Javascript that always sends the date in a known format (preferably `yyyy-mm-dd`), and thus removing any possible ambiguity.

If the data is coming from some other source that you can't control, and you're getting ambiguous input then you need to either just accept that you're going to get it wrong some of the time, or ask the end user / data provider to clarify what they meant.

Comment: I haven't seen mm-dd-yyyy yet, but both mm/dd/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy are quite common - alas, even the same user will happily enter dates both in dd/mm and mm/dd formats, so you can't even say "oh, their locale is `en_US`, so mm/dd/yyyy it is".

Answer (score 0):

If you already have thoses dates at hand, you might have a lot of work ahead of you, but if you have to collect it you can easily force a standard through forms

```
Month : [   ] / Day : [   ] / Year : [    ]
```

and then you build your date through mktime / date in PHP

But if you have already the data at hand, you might have to make some rules to flag weird data since strtotime() will work based on your locale (french and english dates aren't written the same way ie : french date dd/mm/YYYY and english mm/dd/YYYY).

You would have to define a format you want to use and flag all data that doesn't fit in it for manual rework

ie : 12/24/2010 (perfectly makes sense in english date format but that would be 12/12/2011 in french (notice the year change)).

Edit :

Here is a start to review your dates before converting them :

```
<?php

$dates = array('12-12-2010', '24-12-2010','12-24-2010','12-24-10','24-12-10',
               '12-12-10','12/12/2010','24/12/2010','12/24/2010', '12/24/10',
               '24/12/10', '12/12/10','2010-12-12', '2010-24-12','2010-12-24',
               '10-12-24','10-24-12','10-12-12','2010/12/12','2010/24/12',
               '2010/12/24', '10/12/24','10/24/12','10/12/12','11-11-2011');

$regEx = array('YYYY-MM-DD' => '/^(19|20)\d\d[- \/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/',
               'MM-DD-YYYY' => '/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.]((19|20)\d\d)$/',
               'DD-MM-YYYY' => '/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](\d\d)$/',
               'YY-MM-DD' => '/^\d\d[- \/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/',
               'MM-DD-YY' => '/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](\d\d)$/',
               'YY-DD-MM' => '/^\d\d[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](0[1-9]|1[012])$/',
               'No Match' => '//' );


echo '<table style="table-layout:fixed;width:400px">';
echo '<tr>'.'<th>'.'Date'.'</th>'.'<th>'.'PATTERN'.'</th>'.'</tr>';

foreach($dates as $date){
echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $date . ' ';
    echo '</td>'.'<td>';
    foreach($regEx as $name=>$pattern)
        if(preg_match($pattern, $date)){
            echo $name;
            break;
        }
    echo '</td>';

echo '</tr>';
```

}
    echo '';
    ?>

which will give you a table like

```
+-------------+-------------+
| Date        | PATTERN     | 
+-------------+-------------+
| 12-12-2010  | MM-DD-YYYY  | 
| 24-12-2010  | No Match    | 
| 12-24-2010  | MM-DD-YYYY  | 
| 12-24-10    | MM-DD-YY    | 
+-------------+-------------+
```

From that woul will have a way to proceed for building your substring to grab the right parts

Comment: mm/dd/yyyy makes perfect sense in an *American* english sense, but British English use dd/mm/yyyy. As a Brit, I get very annoyed by web sites that try to force me to enter dates in mm/dd/yyyy format, because to me (and I suspect anyone outside of the US), that format makes no sense at all. It's much better to have a calendar control for the user interface, which doesn't rely on dates being entered in any particular fomat. If you must force a format, at least provide a drop-box for months with the month names in it to remove the possibility for confusion.

Comment: @spudley : good point. You could also reorder the form fields based on the user locale

Answer (score 0):

you *could* try the folowing if you realy have to (try to avoid it, others said why):

```
$mysql_timestamp = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($unknown_timestamp));
```

Comment: just give a try that with '12/29/2010' and you will see the out is '1970-01-01' !!!! i am going crazy with this !